# Single Sign On between MVC and VB.net application in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the MVC 4 application hosted on IIS 7.5 and VB.net website hosted on same IIS.

Both have there own login pages.

What I need is, when I login to MVC application and redirect to VB.Net application the login page appears again.

I need the same login credential to be used automatically and get logged in to page.

Tried to use machine key generated in IIS and used in web.config files of both application.

I am using form authentication.

[MVC web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSxSG.jpg)

[VB.Net web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi811.jpg)

Comment: What I would suggest doing in this case would be to have a 3rd application used for handling the login credentials. This way you will avoid duplicating authentication code in both aplpication. You can have a look at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/) for instance. You can then pass along the authentication token given by the login in IdentityServer.

Comment: If this is a public facing website, and those are you real machine key entries, you might want to go and change them ASAP now you've exposed them.

Comment: I would agree with Pac0's suggestion. You need some sort of identity provider which can produce tokens and authenticate them.